# Session is lost with login control in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, session, authentication

After logging in using the Login control the browser loses the session.  This only occurs in Internet Explorer 7.  Has anyone else run into this problem?  If so, do you know a work around?

Comment: Could it be that you a have IE7 set to not accept cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest downloading a tool like [ieHTTPHeaders](http://www.blunck.se/iehttpheaders/download.html) to trace the request/respnonse headers in IE and seeing at what point either IE stops sending the cookie or the server clears it.

You should see a POST to your login page and the server should respond with a Set-Cookie:, and that cookie should be in every subsequent request.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the page, in the process of serving the request, referenced a page that clears the session.  This only happened in IE.